# Can I commit into specific folders inside a repository in GitHub?

Tags: github, repository

As a part of my traineeship, I'm supposed to create a single repository for my final projects.
Inside that repository I'd have created 3 folders (task, project1, project2).

Since I'm quite new to GitHub, I'm not entirely sure how to achieve that.
I know how to create a new repository, but uploading into a specific folder seems extra confusing for a dodo like myself.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new repository (github.com/me/myNewRepo), you can:

- clone it locally
- cd (change directory) to `myNewRepo`
- create your subfolders there (with files in it)
- add/commit and push

You will see those same subfolders in `github.com/me/myNewRepo`

(Replace `Me` by your GitHub user account, and `myNewRepo` by a more meaningful name)